# Graph with ggplot2 a nice boxplot with multiple factors and explicitly defined Standard deviations

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I have a dataframe that only contains the mean value for each group with an explicit number defining the Standard deviation for each group (upper and lower). This is the dataframe:

```
 dat <- read.table(text = '
   mean dist      group     lower     upper rev.lower   factor
 -4.058047    0    P -4.096849 -4.019245 -4.096849  dd
 -4.001524    0 Ps -4.040326 -3.962722 -4.040326  dd
 -3.956972    0    P -4.028551 -3.885393 -4.028551  tt
 -4.050114    0 Ps -4.121694 -3.978535 -4.121694  tt
 -2.859591    0    P -2.955156 -2.764026 -2.955156 aa1
 -3.017559    0 Ps -3.113124 -2.921994 -3.113124 aa1
 -3.094085    0    P -3.196434 -2.991736 -3.196434 aa4
 -3.265121    0 Ps -3.367470 -3.162772 -3.367470 aa4
 -4.283909    0    P -4.352606 -4.215213 -4.352606  ba1
 -4.344173    0 Ps -4.412870 -4.275477 -4.412870  ba1
 -4.594736    0    P -4.664228 -4.525243 -4.664228  bh2
 -4.545442    0 Ps -4.614935 -4.475950 -4.614935  bh2
 -4.843653    0    P -4.925350 -4.761957 -4.925350 g6
 -4.492781    0 Ps -4.574478 -4.411085 -4.574478 g6
 -4.072374    0    P -4.205603 -3.939145 -4.205603 gx
 -3.742987    0 Ps -3.876216 -3.609758 -3.876216 gx',head=T, fill=T)
```

I tried this:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(factor(factor), value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(group)))
```

it works but I am unsure how to graph the lower and upper SD

for each factor for each group. Kindly advise how I may graph this...

many thanks

Comment: i don't think you want a _boxplot_ but a _barplot_. Boxplots are graphics with a box ranging from the 1st to the 3rd  quartiles and lines between min and 1st quartile and 3rd quartile and max. use geom_bar() instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
your_barplot + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=upper,
                              ymin=lower),
                          position=position_dodge(0.9),
                          data=dat)
```

Comment: thank you, it does work, but it is still hard to understand the graph :/ Could you please advise how to make the box be filled from mean to SD? perhaps also make the boxes side by side instead of on each other. Many thanks!

Comment: happy that it works. I did not quite get the additional questions you had. Can you show and example file of output you desire and what you have now instead? You might consider to accept this answer for the sdv problem, and open a new question for additional issues so the users can help you better focusing on specific and updated questions.